# Lidando com colisões em dictionary C#

Tags: c#, .net, detecção-de-colisão, hashmap, dicionário

Preciso mapear um array de strings em um `dictionary` para que eu possa testar posteriormente se uma string informada é valida, verificando se ela faz parte do `dict`, além disso gostaria de recuperar algumas outras informações armazenadas no `dict`.

Para isso estou utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

```
struct reservedWord
    {
        public String command;
        public type token;      //token é um enumerador
    };
```

Ao tentar armazenar a sequência de strings por meio do código (modificações tentando seguir as recomendações do @mgibsonbr):

```
Dictionary<string, string> palavras = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < reservedWords.Length; i++)
        (...)
        palavras.Add(reservedWords[i], word);
```

em tempo de execução é gerada uma exceção pela inserção de chave duplicada. Mesmo quando substituo este código de inserção por

```
palavras.Add(reservedWords[i].getHashCode(), word);
```

recebo a mesma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Eu entendi o erro que você está tendo, mas não entendi exatamente o que você deseja fazer? Você tem um conjunto de palavras-chaves e também outro conjunto de palavras a serem testadas?

Comment: Exatamente isso

Answer (score 3):

### Técnicas para lidar com colisões

A classe `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` do .Net não permitem chaves nulas nem duplicadas. Você terá que lidar com estas ocorrências da forma mais apropriada para o seu uso. Existem várias técnicas que dependem do comportamento que você desejar. No caso de uso de chaves duplicadas, destaco as seguintes:

- **Substituição:** se quiser adicionar um item ao dicionário, substituindo a chave caso ela já exista:

  ```
  dict[chave] = valor;
  ```
- **Adicionar se não existir:**

  ```
  if (!dict.ContainsKey(chave))
       dict.Add(chave, valor);
  ```
- **Recuperar se existir ou adicionar:** se quiser adicionar uma chave/valor, somente se a chave ainda não estiver ocupada, e se estiver ocupada então recuperar o valor já existente:

  ```
  TValor original;
  if (!dict.TryGet(chave, out original))
      dict.Add(chave, valor);
  ```
- **Adicionando múltiplos itens na mesma chave:** se quiser adicionar vários elementos na mesma chave, na verdade teria que usar um dicionário de listas, juntamente com a técnica de adicionar ou recuperar:

  ```
  List lista;
  if (!dict.TryGet(chave, out lista))
      dict[chave] = lista = new List();
  lista.Add(valor);
  ```

### Alguns problemas em potencial que notei no seu código

- Não use o método `GetHashCode()` como chave do dicionário. Este método já será usado internamente pela classe `Dictionary<TChave, TValor>` em todas as chaves, e serve para agilizar o processo de localização de elementos dentro do dicionário.
- A sua `struct` não implementa `IEquatable<T>`, e tampouco é passado um `IEqualityComparer<T>` para o dicionário. Por causa disso, o **hash será extraído do primeiro campo na sua struct**, que é o campo `command`... será que é isso mesmo que você quer? Me parece bem razoável, mas mesmo assim é bom notar isso.
- Sua `struct` possui campos que podem ser alterados depois de inseridos no dicionário. Um tipo que seja usado como chave de um dicionário, não pode ter seu hash alterado, e o **recomendável é que a struct fosse imutável**.

Comment: Miguel, quero quer a hash seja gerada apenas pelo primeiro campo da struct, pois estou usando essa hash para validação de comandos. Gostaria de saber como faço para tornar o primeiro campo da struct imutável. Faz muito tempo que não programo em C#

Answer (score 1):

Bom, um meio de verificar colisões antes de incluir no dicionário, é utilizar o método [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) de Dictionary. Este método permite que você verifique se existe tal chave para cada item do dicionário. Exemplo com um método de extensão:

```
public static bool AddSafe<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))  
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }  
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas misconcepções aqui, precisamos resolvê-las antes de pensar na solução mais apropriada:

1. Há mesmo uma "colisão", ou seu problema são "chaves duplicadas"?

   Se sua massa de dados tem por exemplo a chave "a" mapeando tanto a `1` quanto a `2`, então o problema não é colisão de hash. Colisão seria se tivéssemos "a" mapeando pra `1` e "b" mapeando pra `2`, mas `hash(a) == hash(b)`.

   3 colisões em 59 entradas não me parece "pouquíssima", mas um número excessivo, principalmente se a função de hash for bem feita (como acredito ser o caso com `getHashCode`). Por isso suspeito que seu caso é de chaves duplicadas, mas isso só você pode confirmar. Caso seja isso - e for normal na sua aplicação uma chave apontar pro mesmo valor - então de fato uma solução como a sua proposta (mapear chave a uma lista) seria a correta.
2. Se há uma colisão, de quem é a responsabilidade de tratá-la?

   Colisões podem ocorrer em qualquer função de hash, e as bibliotecas que fazem uso delas estão (ou deveriam estar) preparadas para tratar delas. No exemplo acima, se você inserir "a" e "b" num `Dictionary` e houver colisão entre seus hashes, é obrigação **do Dictionary** fazer algo a respeito, não sua. A menos que essa biblioteca esteja *muito* quebrada (não tenho experiência prática com C#, mas duvido que seja o caso) isso será tratado de forma transparente para o programador-usuário [da biblioteca, i.e. você].

   Seu exemplo acima me leva a pensar se era mesmo um `Dictionary<int, int>` que você queria. Se suas chaves são strings, não seria o caso de usar `Dictionary<string, int>`? Pois se você chama o método `getHashCode` da string manualmente, e usa *seu resultado* como chave (e não a string original) então você está transferindo pra você uma responsabilidade que seria da biblioteca (tratar colisões). Que eu saiba, não há razão para se fazer isso...

Se após ler o exposto acima você ainda precise tratar manualmente de colisões, atualize sua pergunta com mais detalhes e eu procurarei te orientar melhor quanto às suas opções (encadeamento, rehashing...).

Comment: Conforme você comentou, editei o post adicionando mais detalhes sobre o problema. No caso, o hashCode é gerado de acordo com o conteúdo das strings, como não tenho strings duplicadas na minha massa de dados, tenho problemas de colisão e não duplicação. Realmente achei bizarro o dictionary lançar um exception toda vez que tento inserir uma chave duplicada (colisão) e não tratar isso pra mim, mas também não encontrei nenhuma solução melhor. Inclusive, os colegas acima apontaram que a minha abordagem é satisfatória.

Comment: @lfelix Não entendo. O código que você postou não deveria nem compilar! O tipo genérico de `palavras` é `string`, portanto ele deveria aceitar somente strings. Você não quis dizer `Dictionary<reservedWords, string>`? (ou talvez `palavras.Add(reservedWords[i].command, word)`). Além disso, seria bom ter uma lista de strings que estão dando colisão pra gente testar - caso contrário fica difícil reproduzir o problema (você tem poucas strings, mas elas são muito grandes?). Você poderia criar um exemplo no [ideone](http://ideone.com) que mostre o erro acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Outra suggestao era construir o `Dictionary` a volta do proprio `reservedWord` struct, depois de decorra-lo com `IEquatable<reservedWord>`

```
public struct reservedWord : IEquatable<reservedWord>
{
  public string command;
  public MyType token;

  public override int GetHashCode(){ return command.GetHashCode() ^ (int)token; }
  public bool Equals(reservedWord other)
  {
    // seja qual for o teu criteria de egualdade...'case-sensitive'?
    return String.Equals(command, other.command) && token == other.token;
  }
}
```

e depois

```
var palavras = new Dictionary<reservedWord, string>();
var reservedWords = new reservedWord[] { .... }; // lista de struct 'reservedWord'
for (int i = 0; i < reservedWords.Length; i++)
{
    (...)
    if(!palavras.ContainsKey(reservedWords[i])
      palavras.Add(reservedWords[i], word);
}
```